# MySQL databases and Windows Server Backup (Windows 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, backup

I have strange problem. I've turned on incremental backup in Windows Server Backup so if I'm not wrong every backup allows to retrieve files from certain point in time. Does anyone can tell me why when I'm recovering MySQL database data folder I'm getting latest backup instead of backup from point of time which I selected to recover?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would schedule the MySQL backups separately to the Windows Server Backup, for a number of reasons, not least of all the consistency checks and avoiding corruption if there are I/O errors and the data files are corrupt.

That way, your Windows incremental backups can take the backup files (as opposed to the data files) and you will be covered.